# How do I compare if a string is not equal to?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I'm trying to only show something based on if a string is not equal to:

```
<c:if test="${content.getContentType().getName() != "MCE"}">
<li><a href="#publish-history" id="publishHistoryTab">Publish History</a></li>
</c:if>
```

It keeps throwing the error `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/content/manage.jsp(14,60) PWC6212: equal symbol expected`

I've also tried `not eq` instead of `!=`

What is the valid syntax for `not equal to`?

Comment: try "${not (content.getContentType().getName() eq 'MCE')}". Also pay attention to the quotation marks you are using, because the above expression is incorrect.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

[Either `!=` or `ne` will work](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html), but you need to get the [accessor syntax and nested quotes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahu.html#bnahx) sorted out.

```html
<c:if test="${content.contentType.name ne 'MCE'}">
    <%-- snip --%>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Works but Eclipse returns
Syntax error on token "ne", invalid AssignmentOperator